# How can I make my script detect what episode the user has selected so when it plays the next episode it plays it in order? python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm very bad at phrasing my questions properly but hopefully I will be able to clearly explain the problem I'm having as I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it. ( this is my first project )

Ok so I have made a script that will ask the user for a link, then an episode number, so let's say I input the link then enter an episode number of 5.
My script will go to the link and episode number entered, do a series of clicks and boom, automatic tv watching via a certain website. Now I've converted 23 minutes to seconds for import.time time.sleep. Once the time is up, the script will go back to the url that was entered and select an episode, but I have the next part of the script look for 'Episode 2' and then do the series of clicks again. The issue I'm having is I'm not always going to be on episode 1 of what ever tv show I am watching, so my question is how can I get the script to detect this and go to the next episode instead of 'Episode 2'? I was thinking maybe an if statement would work but I'm uncertain on how it would be typed out I tried
if eleml != 'Episode 2'
Next(f)

And I've tried to use continue. What I was thinking is that I could get the script to check to see if it wasn't equal then skip the next 3 lines and check for ('Episode 3') so on and so on until it finds the correct episode.

Here is the full source of my project

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chop.add_extension('Adblock-Plus_v1.10.crx')# installs adblock every time script is ran.

    print ('please input a new url')
    url = input()
    print ('please enter episode number') # enter episode number I.E 1,2,3 etc.
    num = input()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chop)
    driver.get(url)
    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode ' + (num))  #clicks episode + number of episode that is entered by user.
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(10)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('PLAY NOW')

    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(eleml,200,200)
    action.click()
    action.perform()

    import time
    time.sleep(10)

    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(eleml,200,200)
    action.click()
    action.perform()

    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(eleml,200,200)
    action.click()
    action.perform()



    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 2')
    eleml.click()


    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 3')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 4')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 5')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 6')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 7')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 8')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 9')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 10')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 11')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 12')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 13')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)
    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 14')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 15')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 17')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 18')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 19')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 20')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 21')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 22')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 23')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 24')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 25')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 26')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)

    print ('please enter the next season link or a new url')
    new = input()
    driver.get (new)


    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(url)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 1')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 2')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 3')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 4')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 5')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 6')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 7')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.getnew()

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 8')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 9')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 10')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 11')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 12')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 13')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)
    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 14')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 15')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 17')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 18')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 19')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 20')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 21')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 22')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 23')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 24')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 25')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)
    driver.get(new)

    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode 26')
    eleml.click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1320)   

    print ('You have been watching for too long, take a break or restart the script')
```

Please note that I didn't include the website I'm using as I'm uncertain of the rules of this website and didn't want to violate any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the next episode *by link text*:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Episode %d' % (num + 1))
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of doing that, I also appreciate you not adding the int(num), keeps me on my toes!